# modrewrite for css / jss minified

Tags: mod-rewrite, javascript, css

I have a web site hosted in a CentOS 5-Plesk-Apache server. I have recently added a second site to the server for serve dynamic content. I have established  rewrite rules for images (static content) that works pretty well. The module rewrites the URI in the static server to pointing to the the original file.

The problem is that the first site has the minify (http://code.google.com/p/minify/) script installed but i cannot realize how to write a modwrite rule that works, so if I have:

```
<style src='http://www.mystaticserver.com/min/f=style.css'>
```

somewhere, this becomes in the file with this URL

```
http://www.myserver.com/min/f=style.css
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t want a redirect, you could use a [proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) to request that resource internally and pass just the response to the client:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =static.example.com
RewriteRule ^/min/f=.+ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Comment: That is what i need. Thank you (and joschi too)!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use either [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html)'s directive [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) or
[mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for your problem.

A possible rewrite rule (untested) could be:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteRule /min/f=(.*)$ http://www.example.com/min/f=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That rule seems to provoke a redirection (returns a 302 code) that provokes a new GET

Comment: Of course you are right. I forgot the P flag to proxy the request. See Gumbo's answer.